# Converting a JSON with List in Java object

Tags: java, json, objectmapper

I am  trying to convert the below JSON into a Java object using ObjectMapper class in jackson api but i am getting an error.
How my java class should look like?

```
[{
    "saleValue": 100,
    "priceEventTypeCode": 1,
    "startDate": "2016-03-23T18:00:00.0Z",
    "updateStoredValue": true,
    "autoRound": false,
    "priceChangeNumber": "tkt"
},
{
    "saleValue": 100,
    "priceEventTypeCode": 1,
    "startDate": "2016-03-23T18:00:00.0Z",
    "updateStoredValue": true,
    "autoRound": false,
    "priceChangeNumber": "tkt"
}]
```

If i have the below json i am able to convert it to java object.

```
public class Pid
{
    private String priceChangeNumber;
    private String startDate;
    private String autoRound;
    private String priceEventTypeCode;
    private String saleValue;
    private String updateStoredValue;

    // getter and setter functions removed here.
}
```

Json:

```
{
    "saleValue": 100,
    "priceEventTypeCode": 1,
    "startDate": "2016-03-23T18:00:00.0Z",
    "updateStoredValue": true,
    "autoRound": false,
    "priceChangeNumber": "tkt"
}
```

Comment: Are you aware about the Gson class? http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-google-json-parse-json-to-java.jsp have a look at this

Answer (score 2):

ObjectMapper support below method. Use them :)

```
    //To Array
    Pid[] pidArray = mapper.readValue(json, Pid[].class);

    //To List
    List<Pid> pidList1 = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<Pid>>(){});

    //To List Another way
    List<Pid> pidList2 = mapper.readValue(json, mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Pid.class));
```